# Error can't find '__main__' module in 'crop_images_Final.py' in anaconda

Tags: python-3.x

I made a python script, when i run this in anaconda i'm getting an error.I installed all the packages of python.I installed nympy and pillow packages also.

```
can't find '__main__' module in 'crop_images_Final.py'
```

here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import getopt
import os
import glob
import datetime
import numpy as np
# import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET




if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = input('Enter folder path?')
    labelimg_process(folder_path ,image_crop_size = 200, image_size = 224,log = False)
```

can anyone help me to overcome this error

Comment: Do you run this file as a module? If not, you dont need the if ... __name__. But if you need it, are you running in a virtualenv?

Comment: No i'm not running in virtualenv.But it is working in IDLE .

Comment: Can you check the version of python from IDLE and from your terminal? Also, if they point to the same path